# WinJS xhr request responseXML is null in background task

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am creating a windows 8 app using WinJS. I have registered a background task. This works fine. However when I make my xhr request, the responseXML returns null. This works fine when I call it from within my app, but not from the background task. I assume this is because the background task performs limited processing.

Has anyone come across this and know a way around this to get an XML document that accepts querySelector() methods?

problem code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://codepb.com/feed?r=" + Math.random(), reponseType: "document" }).then(function (rss) {

    var items = rss.responseXML.querySelectorAll("item"); //cannot call querySelectorAll on null

    //rest of parsing here
});
```

Update:

This has been acknowledged as a bug by a MSFT. Please see the following forum post for more information: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1fde6e14-9619-43db-8898-b53bf3c5cf2c

Comment: Check out this thread, seems to have happened before: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1fde6e14-9619-43db-8898-b53bf3c5cf2c

Comment: @GotDibbs thanks, I actually found that thread, unfortunately the only solution meant for a complete rewrite of my code, as the windows XMLDocument doesn't support querySelector methods. I was hoping for a solution that did. I can't find any information about it not being supported.

Comment: My guess is that it is a bug, I would suggest opening a case with MSFT if you can, or following up on that thread on the MSDN forums.